# Force Outlook to display from display name in header

Tags: email, header, outlook

I'm sending an email with .net SmtpClient and MailMessage. I set the from to be  `From: Something Else <mysmtprelay@example.com>`.  Note that mysmtprelay@example.com is a valid user on the domain and its display name is "My SMTP Relay".

When I get the email in Outlook 2013, the email from name is "My SMTP Relay" even if in the email header I see this `From: Something Else <mysmtprelay@example.com>`.  Outlook ignore the `Something Else` display name and replace it with the domain name.

Is there a way to force Outlook to use the display name I provided in the From clause?  If I send this email to gmail for example, the display name from the header is used, as expected.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how Exchange works: all incoming sender and recipient names are resolved against GAL. Exchange uses the default display name and SMTP address.