# unable to send mails to outlook 2007 using on behalf of

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, outlook-2007

Our application uses javax.mail.MimeMessage, we are written this code

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@xyz.com", "XYZ"));
```

From section changing work in gmail and yahoo but not working outlook,
can any tell reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `msg.setSender(new InternetAddress(...));`

Comment: hi ,it is working fine in gmail,yahoo,and outlook web but not working in outlook 2007

Comment: Yes but did you actually add the call to setSender IN ADDITION to setFrom? (with different addresses, of course)

Comment: apologies Klitos to unable to convey my requirement exactly.  my requirement is i am sending mail from xyz@company.com ,i don't want to show xyz in from address ,what i want is "xyz on behalf of abc"

Comment: That's exactly my point. When Outlook shows an email message "sent by xyz on behalf of abc" it means that the message contained the header "From: abc" as well as the header "Sender: xyz". Therefore, you need to call msg.setFrom("abc") and msg.setSender("xyz").

Comment: hi ,i found similar question on stackoverflow.check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585704/force-outlook-to-display-from-display-name-in-header   to get exactly what i needed